# In python since ^ sign doesnt mean exponential then how do you do exponential function?

Tags: python, math

I am learning python and Found that Exponetential Operation is Not performed using ^.

In python

```
2 ^ 3 != 8
```

as ^ is Used for Bitwise XOR operations. How can one perform Exponential Function ?

```
2 ^ 3 != 8
```

This doesnt Work.

Comment: you can use `**` or `math.pow()`!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator

Comment: Please search Stackoverflow and perhaps a search engine before posting a question!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `**` operator:

```py
two_to_the_power_of_three = 2**3
```

Answer (score 0):

**use the power operator** '**' , 2 ** 3